# react-native - 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: android, react-native, adb

This is my first react native setup. I started to build with `react-native run android` and got `BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4m 7s` message.

Then the CLI script tried:

```
info Connecting to the development server...

warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": spawnSync adb ENOENT
info Starting the app...

'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

error Failed to start the app.

Error: Command failed: adb shell am start -n com.notez/com.notez.MainActivity
at makeError (S:\Projects (my)\notez\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)  
    at Function.module.exports.sync (S:\Projects (my)\notez\node_modules\execa\index.js:338:15)
```

But I had settled everything up. ADB and SDK paths are defined in my OS ENV config.

So I tried to execute the failed code above on another console:

`adb shell am start -n com.notez/com.notez.MainActivity`

Then it worked! How can I define the 'adb' as an internal or external command as the error refers?

[image: react native app]

Comment: Was the console open when you configured adb in PATH? Then it simply won't have picked it up. Does the command work in the other console in which "adb" worked?

Comment: other console recognized the "adb" and the command is worked but not in react cli script

Comment: I meant: does the react cli command work in the other console?

Comment: oh! i guess i found the issue. it was related to the env variables. thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the enviroment variable `ANDROID_HOME` value from `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\` to `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\` and it worked...

Comment: Before you changed the variable the path was correct, therefore react-native seems to use the wrong path for finding adb.

Comment: I configured it according to the [original document](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) but that didn't work for me, so strange